# How do you define facebook open graph objects with CUSTOM og:tags properties programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I have a website with several thousands of products. I've integrated my site with FB open graph properly.  each product URL now has various FB graph properties such as name, picture, description, which is exactly what I want:

ie. http://graph.facebook.com/283414328378288

HOWEVER, I want to define ADDITIONAL CUSTOM properties such as "price", "short_title", "short_description".  These properties are NOT standard with the FB graph og meta tags.

I have thousands of products so ideally I want to simply add an og tag such as:

```
<meta property="og:price" content="35">
<meta property="og:short_title" content="awesome_product">
```

then after adding that, facebook would pick that up and add it to my open graph object as a custom property... however I am pretty sure that won't work.  Therefore, my question is:

Is there a way to programmatically add custom properties to FB open graph objects WITHOUT going through the Facebook user interface? (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/) obviously by having thousands of changing products.. going through the FB interface would be an unrealistic solution to adding custom properties to objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't; there is no API to update actions, objects, etc. This is something you'll only need to do once, and there's an interface for doing so in the app settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Facebook App, and define the custom OG tags in the OG configuration of the App.